# Combine js files located in non-bundle path

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying to use assetic to combine js files into one. The documentation has the following example:

```
{% javascripts
'@OnlineBundle/Resources/public/js/form.js'
'@OnlineBundle/Resources/public/js/calendar.js' %}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

But I have no js files in my bundles folders, I have them in different path. What should I write instead of '@OnlineBundle/Resources/public/js/form.js' if a js file is located in root_folder/web/assets/js? Can I use twig's `asset` function there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `'@OnlineBundle/Resources/public/js/calendar.js'` type syntax or just "plain" path to your asset (starting from your `root/web` folder):

```
{% javascripts
'@OnlineBundle/Resources/public/js/form.js'
'assets/js/your_js_file.js' %}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```